# lightning:inputfield checkbox not saving

Tags: lightning-aura-components

According tot he documentation, lightning:inputfield should work for checkbox type field.

Here is a snapshot of the code we have:

```
<aura:attribute name="dealershiptTeamRecord" type="IMP_Dealership_Team_Info__c" /> 

<force:recordData aura:id="recordHandler"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.dealershiptTeamRecord}"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordChange}"
                      mode="EDIT"
                      fields="IMP_Team_Closed_Friday__c"
/>

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
    recordId="{!v.recordId.Id}"
    recordTypeId="{!v.recordId.RecordTypeId}"
    objectApiName="IMP_Dealership_Team_Info__c"
    onload="{!c.handleRecordChange}">

        <lightning:inputField   fieldName="IMP_Team_Closed_Monday__c" 
                                value="{!v.dealershiptTeamRecord.IMP_Team_Closed_Monday__c}" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Where `IMP_Team_Closed_Monday__c` is a checkbox field type,

In our case, the form, when saved, always sets the value to false not matter what the checkbox in the UI is set.

Comment: Try using lightning:recordForm in edit mode, without layout type and specifying only that custom field in fields attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<lightning:recordEditForm>` isn't receiving the correct sObject Id.

```
recordId="{!v.recordId.Id}"
```

should be

```
recordId="{!v.recordId}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was a mistake, but that was not the issue. I have other inputFields on the form which work just fine, but not the checkbox type. I checked the permissions on the field, but nothing stands out.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how your form works at all without the sObject Id set correctly. Can you provide a working reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your inputField value to an `aura:attribute`, and then set the value of the `aura:attribute` in `lightning:inputField` as `value="{!v.IsAdHocItemCreationEnabled}"`.
`IsAdHocItemCreationEnabled` is a checkbox field on `ActionPlanTemplate` object.

I was successfully able to save the checkbox field value as selected in the UI.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" 
                access="global" controller="ActionPlanTemplateController" >   
    <aura:attribute name="User" type="String"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="Name" type="String"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="Description" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="IsAdHocItemCreationEnabled" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ActionPlanType" type="String[]"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="TargetEntityType" type="String"/> 
    
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Please Wait" size="small"/>
    </aura:if>
    
    <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium"><b>New Action Plan Template</b></h2>
        </div>        
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium slds-grid slds-wrap ">  
            <c:LookUp
                      aura:id="TemplateOwner-lookup" 
                      value="{!v.User}"
                      Description="Template Owner" 
                      SelectedSObject="{ Name: 'User', Label: 'User', LabelPlural: 'Users', IconName: 'standard:user' }"
                      label="Template Owner"
                      showAdd="false"
                      />
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                                      objectApiName="ActionPlanTemplate" 
                                      onsubmit = "{!c.handleSubmit}"
                                      onsuccess = "{!c.onSave}"                                      
                                  >                             
                <lightning:messages />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" value="{!v.Name}" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Description"  value="{!v.Description}"/>
                <lightning:inputField aura:id="checkboxField" fieldName="IsAdHocItemCreationEnabled" value="{!v.IsAdHocItemCreationEnabled}"/>
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="ActionPlanType" value="{!v.ActionPlanType}"/>
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="TargetEntityType" value="{!v.TargetEntityType}" />
                <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label= "{! $Label.Buttons.save}"  />
                <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="cancel" label="{! $Label.Buttons.cancel}" onclick="{!c.onCancel}" />
            </lightning:recordEditForm>            
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: it'd be great to focus only on what's relevant to the question (in this case, an attribute and the one checkbox `lightning:inputField`) versus sharing unrelated code that makes it harder to read.